# Circuit that simulate very big capacitors - capacitor multiplier

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor

I'm designing a schematic that simulates a battery output that consists of RC branches, as in the example below:

[image: Battery equivalent circuit]

The capacitances involved here reach values of 1 kF. This is because these are not the real capacitances of the cell, and the capacitors here simulate the chemical processes inside.

I'm looking for a circuit that, by using smaller capacitances, will behave, as if larger values are present. Such a circuit may use some active parts, such as an operational amplifier. The only circuit I have found is one that simulates a series RC connection, not a parallel one:

[image: Capacitor multiplier]

Battery simulator is designed for automated testing of prototypes in R&D department. It is much more convenient than a regular battery - you can instantly set a given State-of-charge and observe the behavior of the device under test. Additionally, discharging hundreds of cells to a given level to test all prototypes is very impractical.

Currents there do not exceed 30 mA and voltages are below 4 V.

The input of the RC branch is connected to the battery plus. The output of the RC branch and GND will be connected to the device under test. One commentator wanted to change the circuit so that one end of the simulated capacitor would be connected to the ground. I cannot accept it.

Why? Moving the RC branch from battery plus to minus is not a good idea, because

- it will be difficult to measure the cell and
- more importantly, I plan to use several RC branches, so some of them will not be connected to ground - they will be "hanging".

This device will be used to test the first prototypes. As for off-the-shelf devices, they all simulate only the output resistance, not the RC branches. And they are quite crucial, because the load is mostly pulsed, where the pulse lasts e.g. 1 ms. For such loads the impedance is much lower than for DC. This results in lower voltage drops which are crucial and could cause problems that we will test. Battery filtering (adding capacitance to the output) is not really an option because there is very limited space in the final device.

Do you have any idea how to design such a circuit?

Comment: An old practice has got its glory back. 60 years ago people used often circuits which simulated physical phenomenons. But that was because digital computers and their programs couldn't handle the case in any reasonable time. It was called analog computing. (due the mathematical analogy between the circuit and phenomenon) . Why you do not use a circuit analyzer program and write there C=1kF?

Comment: user287001I am not trying to simulate this battery in a program like spice, but I try to make a real device that will behave like a battery.

Comment: Satisfactory frequency response of the circuit is in the 10-100kHz range.  Currnet rise time of 10mA per 10us will be sufficient. This translate to 1KA/s. If overshoot will be less than 10% it will be great.

Comment: Right values of passive and op amps I could choose by myself. The problem that I have is how circuit should be connected. If it will work for a few kHz i could myself choose elements to broaden frequency response.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable for this Q/A site. But 100kHz for a feedback opamp circuit will be far from trivial.

Comment: Okey, do you have some idea how this circuit could be constrructed for 10 kHz?

Comment: Only an analog computing approach which probably is intolerably complex to be built as fast enough. It's 2 voltage controlled current sources (the ends of the simulated C1) which generate opposite output currents. A control circuit forces the current be C(dU/dt) where U is the voltage between the outputs of the current sources and C is the wanted capacitance. In the preceding idea R1 is a real resistor. It can also be simulated by taking it into the account in the control procedure of the current sources. It adds to the current U/R1.

Comment: This is easily done better with good design spec limits. Try again.  C1max =100kF max,   DC to Slew rate max= C/ESR=T, ESR1 min= ? 25 mOhm, Then always model a battery with Double electric layer effects  C2= ? ESR2=?  C3= optional  Vmax  = 4.2? to define the cell model you want to realize.  Mutliplier factor= 1k min.

Comment: However your battery simulator must load your pulse battery tester with the same current, which is not the same thing as using a smaller cap and simulating the same voltage on a smaller cap with a larger series resistor.  So define I max load simulation as Vmax/ ESR min. Revise your question to list all parameters with tolerances and/or range.  BTW, the above simulation does nothing between two ideal voltage sources, remove the 1k and see for yourself.  (nice idea ,bad example)

Comment: IF you are attempting to validate efficacy of pulse charging over a float charger , the model is no good as there are piezoelectric properties and oxidation aging. thus a BW of 10 MHz may be needed to span possible SRF point with sub nH chemistry

Comment: Since you received a lot of feedback in the comments, resulting in answers which improved your specs, I'd like to kindly suggest that you add this information to the question.

Comment: @piotr - Hi, As explained by *devnull*, questions on Stack Exchange should ideally be edited to include new information and clarifications which happen in comments. A reader should be able to get all important info from the question itself, even without reading comments. Any comments which become obsolete (due to being incorporated into the question) can then be flagged as "no longer needed" for subsequent removal. I have done that process on those comments where I could quickly incorporate your updates into the question. If you can include more updates, please [edit] the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The standard op-amp capacitance multiplier can be modified to have a parallel resistor and a series voltage source as in the following schematic. In this circuit, the two sections in dashed boxes are behaviorally equivalent within the limitations of the op-amp. Since you did not give the exact circuit you wish to emulate, I chose values for the resistances and capacitances, as well as a square wave input, that would make it easy to verify the identical behavior of the two circuits sections. However, if you post what you *really* want, I would be happy to adjust the circuit accordingly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqLxX2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It might be obvious, but

$$A=\frac{\text{ARcell}}{\text{Rcell}}$$

$$\text{AR1} = A*\text{R1}$$

$$\text{C1/A} = \frac{1}{A}{\text{C1}}$$

$$\text{Rcell2} = \text{Rcell}$$

$$\text{Voc2} = \text{Voc}$$

where the italic \$A\$ is the multiplication factor, and non-italic symbols are the values of the identically named components in the schematic.

---

A caveat:

The internal resistance of most cells is quite low. Often lower than the output impedance of an operational amplifier. Depending upon your requirements, it may be necessary to add a boosting mosfet to the op-amp in order to get accurate emulation. Once again, giving your real specs will help give an appropriately accurate circuit.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the case where tossing a CPU at the problem would work best.

The differential equations can be implemented in C very easily. All you need is to have a lab supply, a storage capacitor (potentially a bank of them) to deliver the instantaneous current pulses, and a DAC-controlled current source. The ADC should sense voltage, and adjust the current source to do what you want. Alternately, the ADC can sense the current, and control the voltage source instead.

Choose the circuit bandwidth you want, then a sampling rate at least 3x higher - probably 1-20MHz, take a Raspberry Pi Nano or a similarly fast MCU, select resolution - 16 bits is cheap at those speeds, and you'll get a device that's very flexible and configurable. It'll work much better than an op-amp-based capacitor-using circuit would, and you get data logging for free. You can also use the simulator "in reverse" as an active load to *characterize the batteries*: the simulator can apply pulsed loads to batteries and capture the waveforms, then a fitter program can take those and zero-in on the differential equation that describes battery behavior.

You'll typically want the power supply and idle capacitor voltage to be somewhat higher than what the battery can deliver, to account for inevitable losses and discharge of the capacitor itself.

You'll also want the power control element to be over-designed, i.e. several BJTs or mosfets in parallel, with ample heatsinking. It's an R&D tool and should be robust to be enjoyable.

If you want higher speeds then perhaps an FPGA would be easier to deal with, and you could easily implement any LTI system behavior by combining finite impulse responses at multiple time scales. This also works well with microcontrollers that have some vector operation support to do some MACs (multiply-and-accumulates) in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in a comment that the floating capacitor can be simulated with two controlled current sources. The idea is shown in the next image:

[image]

This works like a capacitor between A and B. Practical current sources actually must be opamp+power transistor devices which have internal control loops which force the current to the wanted value. If we assume that one current direction (sink into terminal A and source from terminal B) is enough the needed operating voltage supplies which actually push the current can be as drawn.

The effective capacitance between A and B is GRC, where G is the transconductance of the controlled current sources and RC is the time constant of the differentiator built around OA1. As a proof we can write for the current:

Current = G * Ux = G * (-RC*(d/dt)(Ub-Ua)) = GRC*(d/dt)(Ua-Ub)

Ua-Ub is the voltage between A and B, so this is the current law of a capacitor which has capacitance GRC. For ex. if G=10 A/V and RC = 100 seconds, the effective capacitance is 1 kF.

The starting value of the voltage in the simulated capacitor can be loaded to C.

There are still numerous open questions:

- how to make the system stable and fast enough with practical current sink and current source circuits. It worked in simulation when OA1 was practical, but both controlled current sources and the diff.amp were ideal (=a substantial amount of practical circuit slowness was omitted)
- how to keep every voltage and current in the circuit in the practical operating area of the components (ideal current sources work in whatever situations)
- how to charge C to the right initial voltage and then switch the capacitor ON without glitches.

One earlier answer suggested DSP. I guess DSP is a realistic option to control the current instead of having a feedback loop which has at least 3 opamps in series.